# Protecting stand-alone variables

Tags: php, oop, variables

Is it possible to protect defined variable from overriding (changing value)? I am making an system which uses plugins and I want to prevent plugin writer (myself) from changing some of specific defined variables (objects that holds new class instances).

Something like this:

```
Class Foo { 
  function __construct() {
    return "Hello";
  }
}
$bar= new Foo();
```

So later, I will be using `global $bar;` in my functions but I don't want to allow changing that variable like this:

`$bar = new Foo();
$bar = "New value";`

`$bar` must always stay the same (new Foo()) since it is going to be a big system and I cannot remember hundreds of core variables I defined.

Ideally would be, if I try to redefine it - php should throw fatal error. Is there a such thing?

Comment: It's called a constant. You can have global constants that you define via `define` keyword or you can have class constants that you define via `const CONSTANT = 'value';`. Protected VARIABLE isn't a variable anymore if it can't change its value.

Comment: I need to protect variable outside of class. It will be object holding a class instance that cannot be redefined.

Comment: @N.B. can I hold class instance in `define` keyword? I though it only works for `string`, `boolean` and `integer/double/float` types?

Comment: The solution to make sure your globals aren't being modified is to stop using globals.

Comment: You can't have constants contain objects. It'd be easier if you told us what you want to achieve and why. It'll be easier to help you that way. If you can tell us what object you want to "protect" and why, it's much easier to suggest how to do it.

Comment: @N.B. I am creating a SQL class that will be using mysqli with logging and some other modifications. Then I will be calling a single instance of that class like `$db = new SQL();` and I will be using `$db` from then on in every other function and tasks. What I want is to protect `$db` somehow so I cannot change it to something else if I get lost in code.

Comment: Instead of "protecting" the variable from being modified, make the class return only one instance. I'll get crucified for this, but what you're looking for is singleton pattern (for now of course, singletons have their own issues when it comes to unit testing the code).

Comment: Instead of using `$db = new SQL()` use `$db = SQL::instance()` and make sure the `instance()` method of that class returns an instance of the class (also known as a Singleton Pattern as noted by 10 other people on this page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

```
class Foo
{
    protected static $instance = null;
    protected function __construct()
    {
        throw new Exception('use ::getInstance()');
    } 

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(static::$instance)) {
            static::$instance = new static;
        }
        return static::$instance;
    }
}
```

use:

```
$bar = Foo::getInstance();
```

any one can redeclare $bar .. but if they wont the real Foo ... they need to get the instance;

Comment: So basically there's no way from preventing `$bar` to be redeclared?

Comment: However, this one is the closest to what I want to achieve. Waiting if someone come up with more answers, otherwise I will accept it.

Comment: Instead of using `$bar` in your code, just use `Foo::getInstance()` whenever you need it. This way you will be sure you are always working with an object you like and not some variable, whose type you don't know, or maybe isn't even defined.

Comment: There is no reliable way of protecting a global variable $bar and its contents from being redeclared unless you use `define()`, but I don't think it supports defining whole objects.

Comment: @NikolaR. yes there is: yo do not redeclare it. You should look into dependency injection better than singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your constructor returning a string? By definition a constructor returns a reference to an object.

If you just want a a reference to a string that cannot change, why not just make a const?

```
const STRING_THAT_WONT_CHANGE = 'foo';
```

Comment: That was a demo constructor, just example.